# Cannot read property 'list_ids' of undefined

Tags: object, typescript, null, undefined

I am new on Typescript and I don't know how to solve a trivial issue I guess.
I've declared a new class, and then I want to assign the values I got from the apiCall. But the problem I've get is:

> Cannot read property 'list_ids' of undefined

On my class, I inicializated the object, and if I want to declare it empty, it appears a mistake. 
How can I solve this? If I could declare it empty from the beggining and then assign it, it would be great I guess!

Here I post the code of my class:

```
export class MyClass {
 name: string 
 op: string 
 field_id: string
 comparsion_values: {
  values: [
    string
  ],
  list_ids: [number] 
  field_ids: [
    string 
  ],
  velocities: [
    string 
  ],
  prices: [
    {
     amount: 0 
     currency: string 
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

I Inizializate it as: `myObjectClass= new myClass;`

And the problem appear when I try to do a push in some of my arrays.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

Based on the naming, I assume you intended `list_ids`, `field_ids` to be arrays, but currently they are typed as [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).

**Problem 2:**

You are not initializing your `comparsion_values` property. You are simply defining the type for the property.

You can define the type for `comparsion_values` in an interface (there is nothing wrong with defining it inline, but it looks messy) and initialize it with empty arrays in the constructor like below:

```
interface ComparisonValues {
    values: Array<string>, // Or string[] would work too
    list_ids: Array<number>
    field_ids: Array<string>,
    velocities: Array<string>,
    prices: Array<{
        amount: number
        currency: string
    }>
}

export class MyClass {
    name: string
    op: string
    field_id: string
    comparsion_values: ComparisonValues
    constructor() {
        this.comparsion_values = {
            values: [],
            list_ids: [],
            field_ids: [],
            velocities: [],
            prices: []
        }
    }
}
```